# Is Postman Java based tool?

Tags: rest, postman

I am testing a rest web service using PostMan tool. Is PostMan a java based client tool?. I am able to run the service using a Java based client, but get an error with .net client.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but whether the endpoint were written in Java or C# should have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

postman is a tool for testing webservices and it does not depend on any language provided your rest endpoints are up and running everything should work no matter the language used in the backen

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can run [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman) as a Java**Script** module like :

```
var newman = require('newman');

newman.run({
   collection: '/path/to/collection.json',
   reporters: 'myreporter',
   reporter: {
     myreporter: {
       'option-name': 'option-value' // this is optional
     }
   }
}, function (err, summary) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.info('collection run complete!');
});
```